# git subdirectory which is ignored

Tags: git

I have a project named 'myproject' which is version-controlled by git. It has a subdirectory named 'data' which is gitignored.

Can I 'git init' for data directory and manage it as a separate git tree?
I tested it and it seems to work.
But I am not sure if that's a good practice and has potential problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that should be fine. I've done that many times before, with no problems.

Answer (score 7):

If the parent repository depends on the 'data' repository being a specific version, you might want to consider [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). This will allow the parent repository to point to a specific commit of the 'data' repository. Even if the two are compatible now they may not be in the future.

I don't have much detail on your use-case and how 'myproject' relates to 'data', so submodules may over-complicate things for you.

Comment: +1 Submodules can get really complicated, but not more complicated than managing multiple nested repos : )